# SSRS- Account and Contact

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement such that there is one parameter XXX field(in CRM) which we have for both contact and account(which should be a dropdown parameter). If the user is entering some value in XXX and selecting contact or account from that drop down parameter. The results have details(which is few other fields like address etc.) depending upon the contact or account the user selects. Firstly, Is it possible to get contact and account in dropdown(since contact and account both are datasets). Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You might want to mention that this is an SSRS report parameter, and state your version of CRM.

Comment: Dynamics 365(on premise) and SSRS 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Whatever you want, write the query from filteredviews & prepare the dataset for parameter. Bind it to combobox using the steps below. (Though you can have combined account+contact in one combobox using union query & addl. parameter of account/contact identifier dropdown, I won't recommend it)

1. Right click the parameter
2. Select "Available Values" section
3. Click the "Get values from a query" option
4. Select the appropriate dataset and fields

[image]

How many records we are talking here? 10s, 100s, 1000s. You can have a search box to filter the bulk data. [Read this article](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/add-text-parameter-filtering-bulk-data/)

[Refer this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2844/working-with-multiselect-parameters-for-ssrs-reports/) with detailed steps for full understanding of cascading filters/multi-select params in SSRS reporting.